# String comparison in C(Game project)

Tags: c

I am making a little game, in which I would like to make string comparison, to compare 2 strings, and if they are equal I would like to print it out.:

I included `stdio.h` and `string.h` I use *codeblocks*.
I tried to run the code, but codeblocks says

> code.exe has stopped working

Could someone help me? 
The code looks like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    typedef struct {
        char * name;
    } player;

    int player_number;
    player players[100];

    printf("What's your name?\n");
    scanf("%s",&players[0].name);

    printf("How many players are playing the game?\n");
    scanf("%d", &player_number);


    printf("Can you name your friends?\n");
    int d;
    for(d=1;d<player_number;d++)
    {
        scanf("%s", &players[d].name);
    }

    printf("Who is starting the game?\n");
    char * starter;
    scanf("%s",&starter);

    int e;
    for(e=0;e<player_number;e++)
    {
        if(strncmp(players[e].name, starter, 10)==0)
        {
            printf("%s is starting the game",starter);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try using codeblocks' debugger.

Comment: You haven't allocated space for the name, only for a pointer to a string. Also, `&players[0]` has type "pointer to struct player", not pointer to char. You should crank up your compiler's warning level!

Comment: Should I redifine struct player like this?
typedef struct {
    char name[20];
    }player;  What should i do? &players[0] works. String comparison is the part that is not working

Comment: Last 9 or 10 lines are not working? When i comment them, everything is fine?
How should i make them work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have some memory for `char *starter` to point at.

Here's your mistake.

```
char * starter;
scanf("%s",&starter);
```

also here;

```
typedef struct {
char * name;
}player;
```

Instead try this;

```
typedef struct {
char name[100];
}player;

char starter[100];
scanf("%s",starter);
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you! I changed this; char * name; to char name[20]; and this char * starter; to this char starter[100];

Comment: Thank you very much! I am a newbie, so i didn't knew that!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know C that much but shouldn't there be a `.name` in the first input?

It should look like I suppose:

```
printf("What's your name?\n");
scanf("%s",&players[0].name);
```

Comment: You're right, i will change that. I was translating the Croatian code on english, so i forgot that part. But still the function strncmp does not work.